# How to convert short to ASCII?

Tags: c, embedded, converters

What is the best way(optimized by speed) to  convert a short number to ascii in **C** (-1,5,1000 to "-1","5","1000").

I need it for embedded MCU, so the `sprintf()` is not an option.

Thanks

Comment: `I need a code`.. DV magnet. :-)

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694100/converting-to-ascii-in-c ?

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service here. :-)

Comment: No this is not works well, have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

As [@Potatoswatter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153285/potatoswatter) succinctly comments, use standard `itoa()` is you have it.

As to what is fastest: best to profile candidate solutions.  What works best on one platform may differ on another.

Below is an alternative implementation.  Flowing is a tight recursive solution that does not need to reverse its results. It works for all `int`: `[INT_MIN, INT_MAX]` as it works with the negative side of `int` which is the same size or larger than the positive side.

```
static char *itoa10_helper(int n, char *s) {
  if (n <= -10) {
    s = itoa10_helper(n / 10, s);
  }
  *s = (char) ('0' - n % 10);
  return ++s;
}

char* itoa10(int n, char *s) {
  if (n < 0) {
    *s = '-';
    *itoa10_helper(n, s+1) = 0;
  } else {
    *itoa10_helper(-n, s) = 0;
  }
  return s;
}

#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define INT_MAX_SIZE (sizeof (int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)

int main(void) {
  char buf[INT_MAX_SIZE];
  puts(itoa10(0, buf));
  puts(itoa10(123, buf));
  puts(itoa10(INT_MAX, buf));
  puts(itoa10(INT_MIN, buf));
  return 0;
}
```

---

A fast solution, that returns a pointer *somewhere* in the buffer provided follows:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

char* itoa10f(int n, char *buf) {
  char *s = buf + INT_MAX_SIZE - 1;
  *s = '\0';
  bool isnegative = n < 0;
  if (!isnegative) {
    n = -n;
  }
  do {
    *(--s) = (char) ('0' - n % 10);
  } while (n /= 10);
  if (isnegative) {
    *(--s) = '-';
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: In other words, use `itoa`.

Comment: In what standard is `itoa` "standard"?

Comment: @AnT `itoa()` is commonly found in many compilers over last decades: Unix, [Xenix](http://www.polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=itoa&af=0&tf=2&of=Xenix), Kernighan and Ritchie, Borland/Turbo C, and many embedded platforms, I've never seen it as a standard function in [C spec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) nor is it presently (if ever) in [Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190229/where-is-the-itoa-function-in-linux).  It's common as the C standard alternative `sprintf(buf, "%d", i)` is expensive as in embedded platforms.

Comment: What is the value of CHAR_BIT?

Comment: @user3428151 `CHAR_BIT` is found in `<limits.h>`.  It is often 8.   Did not `#include <limits.h> #define INT_MAX_SIZE (sizeof (int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)` compile for you?  What compiler are you using?

Comment: it is compiled, It works, but still for my embedded issues it is slow, have 15 int numbers that i need to print over UART to PC, 

UART is 2M
MCU 28MHz
DATA ready sampled at 1.6Mh

Comment: @user3428151 1) consider transmitting as hexadecimal characters, certainly faster to convert to `0-9,A-F` than decimal.  2) A UART transmitting at 2M baud (2 Mbits/sec) cannot keep up with data sampled at 1.6MHz even if conversion time was 0 seconds unless code sends less than < 2.0 _bits_ per sample.  Transmitting `"1000"` would take 4*10 bits.  Suggest re-think / clarify goals.